# Pulumi: Class not found kubernetes.core_v1.ConfigMap and EKS cluster

Tags: java, kubernetes, amazon-eks, pulumi

I'm trying to PoC pulumi and the eks module.

My code is really simple for now but I have a weird exception:

```java
import com.pulumi.eks.Cluster;
import com.pulumi.eks.ClusterArgs;

public class EKS {

public Cluster createEKS(Network network, Context ctx) {
 Role role = getClusterRole();

 var cluster = new Cluster("pulumi-cluster", ClusterArgs.builder()
   .minSize(2)
   .maxSize(5)
   .desiredCapacity(2)
   .vpcId(network.vpc().id())
   .version("1.27")
   .instanceType("t2.small")
   .publicSubnetIds(network.subnetsEksId())
   .privateSubnetIds(network.subnetsEksId())
   .serviceRole(role)
   .build());
}

    private Role getClusterRole() {
        var role = new Role("pulumi-eks-role", RoleArgs.builder()
                .assumeRolePolicy(
                        """
                                {
                                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                                    "Statement": [
                                        {
                                            "Effect": "Allow",
                                            "Principal": {
                                                "Service": "eks.amazonaws.com"
                                            },
                                            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                                """).build());

        new RolePolicyAttachment("pulumi-eks-policy-attachment",
                RolePolicyAttachmentArgs.builder()
                        .policyArn("arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy")
                        .role(role.id()).build());
        return role;
    }
}
```

where network works fine and define my vpc / subnets and role an eks admin policy.

When I run a `pulumi up`, I get the following:

```java
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/pulumi/kubernetes/core_v1/ConfigMap
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:315)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:320)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:649)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.exec(CompletableFuture.java:483)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:387)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1312)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1843)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1808)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:188)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/pulumi/kubernetes/core_v1/ConfigMap
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3578)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2676)
        at com.pulumi.serialization.internal.Converter.processSetters(Converter.java:851)
        at com.pulumi.serialization.internal.Converter.collectSetters(Converter.java:847)
        at com.pulumi.serialization.internal.Converter.checkTargetType(Converter.java:829)
        at com.pulumi.serialization.internal.Converter.checkTargetType(Converter.java:675)
        at com.pulumi.serialization.internal.Converter.convertValue(Converter.java:78)
        at com.pulumi.core.internal.OutputCompletionSource.setValue(OutputCompletionSource.java:95)
        at com.pulumi.deployment.internal.DeploymentImpl$ReadOrRegisterResourceInternal.lambda$completeResourceAsync$0(DeploymentImpl.java:1187)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:646)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pulumi.kubernetes.core_v1.ConfigMap
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:593)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
        ... 17 more
```

I have a package from com.pulumi:kubernetes dependency which is `com.pulumi.kubernetes.core.v1.ConfigMap` but not with an *_*

Do you know where this error comes from ?

pulumi version: v3.84.0

pulumi-kubernetes: 4.3.0

pulumi-eks: 1.0.3

pulumi-aws: 6.3.0

kubectl: 1.28

Comment: Please post the full code, including imported dependencies

Comment: done @jaxxstorm